# laravel join query throws a column not found error

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel throws a column not found error when i try to join the tables. whats causing this error because i tried to join the tables in phpMyAdmin and the mysql query worked. `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select`posts`.`id`from`posts`inner join`posts`as`p`on`p`.`category_id`=`categories`.`id`)`

### postcontroller

```
$test = Post::select( 'posts.id')
->join('posts as p', 'p.category_id', '=', 
'categories.id')
->get();
```

### category model

```
public function categoriesToPost()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

### post model

```
 public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Your join is wrong. You're asking it to join itself as p. Rather than having the join on the categories. E.g. `Post::select('posts.id')->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->get()`

Comment: @ChewySalmon thanks i was getting it all wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your join is off.

You haven't specified which table you want to join, and as a result the column is unknown.

The solution would be to do the following:

```
$test = Post::select('posts.id')
            ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->get();
```